# PHP - Simple Html Dom load multiple pages speed

Tags: php, parsing, dom, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I finally got my script to work but it takes a long time to do the search (via ajax). Basically by entering a keyword, it searches the page and captures all the titles, urls, and thumbnails of the videos. But the problem arose to me to capture the tags that were inside each video, so I had to forcibly access each video to capture the tags, the only way I could think of was to add a loop inside the loop that captures the found videos that is to say:

For each video found -> Capture title, thumbnail, URL -> With captured URL -> Go to that URL and capture your tags.

The code I used is basically the following, I need to know if there is any other method to speed up searches, either by optimizing the code or using another way:

My parse function:

```
<?php
function dlPage($href) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Accept-language: en-US");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4");
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Create a DOM object
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $dom->load($str);

    return $dom;
    }
?>
```

My script:

```
$buscartag = str_replace(' ', '+', $_POST['buscartag']);
$urlparse = "https://example.com/?k=".$buscartag;

$paginas = rand(0, 50);
$html = dlPage($urlparse."&p=".$paginas);   
$counter = 0;

foreach($html->find('div.video-box') as $videos) {

    if ($videos) {
        $titulo = $videos->find('div.video-box>p[!class])>a[!class]',0)->attr['title'];

        $pathvideo = str_replace('_', '', $videos->attr['id']);
        $link = "https://www.example.com/".$pathvideo."/";
        $thumb = $videos->find('div.thumb')->innertext

                //HERE MY SECOND BUCLE FOR TAGS!!!
                $gettags2 = array();
                $html_tags = file_get_html($link);
                foreach ($html_tags->find('a.nu') as $gettags){
                    $gettags2[] = $gettags->innertext;

        if (!empty($titulo) && !empty($link) && !empty($idvideo) && !empty($urlimagen)){
                    $counter++;
                    //here will echo all variables
        }}
```

Comment: Implement some caching / persistent storage then. Hopefully `example.com` is allowing you to do this.

Comment: How could I do it?